# How to know the var name passed in parameter for a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have (example):

HTML:

```
<button id="playlist01"></button>
<button id="playlist02"></button>
<button id="playlist03"></button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var playlist01 = [];
  var playlist02 = [];
  var playlist03 = [];

  $("button").click(function() {
    pushSong( $(this).attr("id") );
  });

  function pushSong(id) {
    playlist??.push("whatever"); //playlist01, playlist02 or playlist03 ??
  }
});
```

There are an array for each button with the id as var name.

When I click a `<button>` tag, I call the function with the id of the button as a parameter, and then, I push something in the array with the ID passed in the function, but, how can I know the `playlist?` name?

Thank you and greetings!

Comment: Use a collection (an array or an object) of playlists, not multiple variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your playlist arrays in an object whose keys correspond to the IDs. Then use the id to retrieve the correct playlist array, then push.

```
var playlists = {
  playlist01: [],
  playlist02: [],
  playlist01: [],
};

function pushSong(id) {
  playlists[id].push("whatever");
}
```

Comment: It works! but, how can I push a new playlist04 into playlists dynamically? (If I don't know the name, but I have it in a var like `playlists.push($foo: []);` )

Answer (score 1):

All variables are scoped to their closest [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). All functions are closures. Your variables are in the scope and context of the outer function, so, if you pass the context of the outer function to the `pushSong` function, you can do:

```
function pushSong(id) {
    this[id].push("whatever");
};
```

[Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the function by passing the current `this` where the variables are scoped:

```
pushSong.call(this, $(this).attr("id"));
```

[Learn more about scope and context in JavaScript.](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch statement so you have a case for each possible Playlist, otherwise you need to use a series of else if statements.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Or change it to use a double array playlist[][] and [1][] for the first [2][] for the second etc.